# Find all the integer solutions of: $ x^{2} - 10y^{2} = 1 $

Tags: number-theory

I'm totally clueless about this question:

Find all the integer solutions of: $ x^{2} - 10y^{2} = 1 $ .

I need someone's advice, I don't have any idea in my mind. 
Thank you very much

Comment: Pell's equation.

Comment: What context are you coming across this problem?  There is a way to solve it using continued fraction convergents of $\sqrt{10}$, you could attempt to study the ring of integers in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{10}]$, but there are likely other solutions as well.  The perspective you have will help the community figure out what is most appropriate.

Comment: I learned congruences, fermat's theromes, euler theoerm, cylic groups..  legendre symbols and resuidues, that's all

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479035/

Comment: The fundamental solution is I think $(19,6)$. Other solutions can be expressed in terms of powers of $19+6\sqrt{10}$, there is also a nice recurrence. But knowing this requires some knowledge of the Pell equation.

Comment: Odd how the subconscious works. Before I even began trying to try to solve it the fact that $19^2 =361$ popped unbidden to mind leading immediately to $(19,6)$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: My subconscious was not working, I squared $3+\sqrt{10}$.